# juju no route to host

Tags: networking, ssh, juju, maas, openstack

I have set up a system as described below.

A server connected to the internet(192.168.16.250) and also to a switch(10.1.1.100). I have nat configured on the switch facing interface and can access the internet from behind the switch.

I have installed maas on the server and configured `10.1.1.100/MAAS` as my maas api url and have four systems commissioned. The problem I am facing is that when I try to bootstrap juju, it gives a `ssh: connect to host 10.1.1.151 port 22: No route to host` error after the node is deployed by maas. I have configured `10.1.1.101 - 10.1.1.150` as the DHCP pool and `10.1.1.151 - 10.1.1.200` as the static pool on maas for the switch facing interface. Can someone please help me ?

Thanks.

Edit: While the deployment phase of bootstrapping is going on, I can ping the host. But after that, during the bootstrap phase, the ping returns `Destination Host Unreachable`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the issue was not enough time. Solved after adding `bootstrap-timeout: 1800` to `.juju/environments.yaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into IP forwarding on the MAAS server.

The nodes being managed by MAAS server try to reach internet via MAAS server i.e; MAAS server acts as the default gateway. So even if you configure NAT on the 10.x.x.x switch, the nodes will try to contact the MAAS server to reach internet.

Take a look at these issues:
https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/883

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-openstack/issues/235

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue... showing no route to host when i tried to deploy service to my juju node(including bootstrap node)
initially everything is ok..i can deploy without any issue.
But after I enable node1(ready state in MAAS) eth1(go to internet by using dhcp, using NAT from my host machine) .. all my deployment are failed.

[all showing:\2016-08-10 08:57:29 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 cannot add unit 1/1 to service "mediawiki": cannot add unit to service "mediawiki": Get http://192.168.122.3/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/?op=list&status=0&status=1&status=4&status=5&status=10: dial tcp 192.168.122.3:80: no route to host
}
192.168.122.3 is my MAAS public IP.

then later I notice i even can not telnet 192.168.122.3 80 from other nodes.
So I stop the eth1 on one of the node then can deploy service successfully.

hope it can help someone...
if you have any question let me know.